# How do I completely remove Apache2?

Tags: server, apache2, webserver, webapps

I need to completely remove apache2 but no matter what I do I still get the default ubuntu page and when I run a nodejs app it will say port 80 is in use.

I tried the usual suggested in other apache2 removal questions:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove

rm -rf /usr/sbin/apache2
rm -rf /etc/apache2
```

$ sudo lsof -i :80

```
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
chrome  2426 physiii  184u  IPv4  31202      0t0  TCP desktop:54128->151.101.193.69:http (ESTABLISHED)
chrome  2426 physiii  248u  IPv4  27504      0t0  TCP desktop:54038->151.101.193.69:http (ESTABLISHED)
chrome  2426 physiii  258u  IPv4  27510      0t0  TCP desktop:33542->174.76.226.31:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

I still get "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" if I go to 127.0.0.1

What is going on?

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `sudo lsof -i :80`, please.

Comment: Note: **`sudo`** in `sudo lsof -i :80`.

Comment: Just noticed that :) updated.

Comment: Something's clearly changed - your older output had a connection to localhost, which is no longer present. Do you still have something running on port 80? I doubt it.

Comment: In my case, wanted to replace apache2 with nginx, but was confused when apache2's default page was still served. `sudo lsof -i :80` was the clue for me. It turned out it was nginx now serving the exact same folder  `/var/www/html/`.

Comment: angluarsen's comment was my exact problem

Answer (score 4):

In my case, these commands helped me to fully remove `apache2`.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove apache2*
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2 /var/lib/apache2
```

Comment: Still there. I'm using 16.04

Comment: After the page loads to default apache page. Refresh it again.

Comment: Nope. I can't start a program on port 80. Apache is still binding that port somehow!